# iOS 11 UISearchBar in navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, ios11

The UISearchBar behaves different in iOS 11 then in iOS 10 and below.

- the size has changed
- the fade-out animation when pushing another view controlled is missing

I handled to "fix" the size somehow with this code:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
}
```

But I can't fix the animation. Any ideas, apart from just animating the search bar manually on push?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    strongSelf.searchBar.alpha = 0.0
})
```

See a video of the broken animation effect [here](https://youtu.be/ERk-raZagQw).

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look answer in [UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipercentdriveninteractivetransition). It's using for update UIViews during UINavigationController transition in persentage value.

Other words, depends on how much UINavigationController already opened next view controller or move backwards views will have different appearance.

This value will help you update your search bar (alpha, width, etc.)

Comment: It's the most right and easy way to manage such things. You will find a lot of examples in web. Sorry I didn't prepare any code because I was doing this long scince and a lot of code might be depracted for iOS 10+

Comment: From your answer it's not obvious how to add animation to UISearchBar.

Comment: This seems like a good answer but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Same, how to do it? Do I have to make custom transition just to take care of the search bar opacity?

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap it with a UIView, and the animation comes back.

Comment: Then the UIView disappears completely. Do I have to specify the sizes for it?

Comment: @awuu,i got a similar question in iOS11 , when i use a UISearchBar as titleView , and when i pop this controller out , the ViewController now is showing will be some distance apart from the navigation bar , and when i do as you said ,wrap the searchbar in view ,and then set this view as titleView , this problem will not happen , but i still wondering why is this happen?

Comment: @Sti yes. autolayout will do that.

Comment: @ximmyxiao, i guess it's a Apple's bug, Apple changes NavigationBar a lot because of the LargeTitles of iOS 11.

Comment: @ximmyxiao, I have almost the same issue, but with setting UISearchBar as a UITableVIew's tableHeaderView.

Comment: If you wrap it with UIView then UISearchBar has strange dimensions and it's impossible to edit text in it.

Comment: @ArtemM yeah , wrap the searchBar may fix it for u